# Compute mobx value from action

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm currently refactoring a FreeCodeCamp repo as way to learn mobx. What I'm trying to do is calculate `this.store.studentCount` as you can see in the StudentModal Component. Take a look here:

This is my `/client/src/components/students/Modal.js`

```
@observer
@inject('StudentModal')
export default class StudentModal extends Component {

  store = new this.props.StudentModal()

  renderStudentCount() {
    let message
    if (this.store.studentCount > 1) {
      message = `${this.store.studentCount} students`
    } else {
      message = `${this.store.studentCount} student`
    }
    return <div id="student-count">{message}</div>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AddStudentForm">
        <div className="class-table-button-container">
          <Button
            onClick={this.open}
          >
            Add Student
          </Button>
          {this.renderStudentCount()}
        </div>
        .....
    )
  }
}
```

Taking a look at my models for the Modal component you can see I need to fetch a service to get the length of this but for whatever reason I cannot set the studentCount to a new value.

This is my `/client/src/models/students/Modal.js`

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'
import StudentsService from '../../services/StudentsService'

export default class StudentModal {    
  @observable open = true

  @observable studentCount = 0

  @action
  fetchStudents() {
    StudentsService.fetchStudents().then(response => {
      const studentCount = response.body
      this.studentCount = studentCount.length
    })
  }
}
```

You can take a look at the full source code here: https://github.com/imcodingideas/classroom-mode/tree/mobx-migration which I should remind you that this is open-source.

Am I doing this correctly? Do you have any feedback for me?

Comment: When using both the observer and inject decorators, the observer decoratot should be applied first (closest to the class declaration)

Comment: Can I inject two stores on the same class? Say for example I need to compute the length of an array but that lives in another component. How could I handle that?

Comment: you can inject as many things as you want. However, you cannot use state from a sibling or child component in a clean way. In the React philosophy you have to pull the state up to the common parent, or since you are using mobx, you can actually pull it completeely out your component  and define a separate 'store' for that state, which is probably the cleanest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some minor things:

### Identical class names

This might lead to problems since, both your store and react component are called `StudentModal`

### decorator order

as @Joseph suggested swap the order around your class:

```
@inject("StudentModal")
@observer
export default class StudentModal
```

### State management

```
 store = new this.props.StudentModal()
```

On creation of every StudentModal you seem to create a new state store. Normally te store is instantiated once (unless you really want seperate stores per modal) inside your entry point and then used later on:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
var stores = { StudentModal: new StudanModalStore() }
render(
        <Provider {...stores}>
            <StudentModal />
        </Provider>,
    rootEl,
);

@observer
@inject('StudentModal')
export default class StudentModal extends Component {
    //used getter instead of setting once
    // no longer use `new` but directly reference instance of the store. 
    get store (): StudentModalStore { return this.props.StudentModalas; }

}
```

above code is in typescript.

Comment: I cannot believe even writing this post that I had identical class names. :(

Comment: @JosephChambers happens to the best of us, try suffixing (even though some say its a code smell) stores with Store to prevent ;-)